# Objective-C Loop Through NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, foreach

Very simple question - how might I iterate through a NSMutableArray and do things for each item?

Much like the for loop in other langs:

```
foreach(array)
{
    dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to call a method in each one, use

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(eatFish)];
```

or if you want to pass an argument,

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(eat:) withObject:myFishObject];
```